# Print lines with a given value

Tags: python

I am trying to run some simple code in python to read a text file and print only lines with a certain value in the last column.

This is the text file:

```
234 324 4
124 35 5
13 434 7
34 465 1
41 46 2 
25 62 2
```

and my attempted code is

```
data = np.loadtxt('SelectValueTest.txt')

line = range (0,5)
for line in data:
    for n in data[:,2]:
        if n ==1:
            print line
```

I know that I need to change the `print line` bit as this is just printing every line if any of them include to value `1`, but I'm not sure what to put?

Sorry for the really basic question! I'm just starting out and struggling to get the hang of it!

Comment: What actually in a data variable? Show us.

Answer (score 3):

Just split each line on space, and check whether the last element of the list obtained is equal to the required value or not: -

```
with open('SelectValueTest.txt', 'rb') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.strip().split(" ")[-1] == '1':
             print line
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Ive tried to use this solutions and im getting the error: 
object has no attribute 'split'

Also, in case itll make any difference, this file was just a quick one i made to test the code, rather than running it on the large one i need to use later. in that the column im searching in the second to last one, so in that case would i just change [-1] to[-2]? I realise this is probably jumping the ugn a bit seeing as i cant even work out this little bit!

Comment: sorry, i hit enter too fast for the last comment

Comment: @user1841859.. That code is not complete. I assume that you read your lines one by one in `line` variable from your `data`. Where `data` I assume is the `file` reference. So, your `line` should contain the string. On which you can call split function.

Comment: @user1841859.. And please post what exactly are you searching. Last column or second last column?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('SelectValueTest.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().endswith('1'):
            print line
```

That will print out all lines ending with 1.  You need the strip() to remove the newlines etc at the end of the lines. This will work with the data you showed us. However, if you have values with 2 or more digits at the end of the lines, then Rohit's method is what you will need to use.

Mike

Comment: Keep in mind this will only work if the lines end with single digit numbers. If they ever end with anything >9 this will produce an incorrect result.

Comment: Exactly right. I edited the post to note that. But this will work for the data shown.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is happening is you are printing any line that contains a 1 in it, anywhere.

A better solution would be to read it with cvs reader, like this:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
    data= csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for line in data:
        if line[-1] ==1:
            print line
```